# How to prove the 1 Lipschitz function defined on the closed unit ball has a fixed point

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, lipschitz-functions

I need to prove that the 1 Lipschitz function has a fixed point:

$\|f(x)-f(y)\|≤ \|x-y\|$ for all $x,y\in B$, where $B$ is the closed unit ball in the $R^n$.

I want to apply the contraction mapping theorem. The contraction mapping theorem is not suitable for 1 Lipschitz function because it requires that $\lambda \in [0,1)$, so I want to modify this function to obtain a contraction. Anyone could please gives me some hints about how to get such contraction?

Comment: Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815708/every-1-lipschitz-function-in-the-closed-unit-ball-has-a-fixed-point

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: Hi, is there a reason why you unaccepted the answer below? If there is something wrong, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(1-{1 \over n}) f$ is $(1-{1 \over n})$ Lipschitz and so has a fixed point $x_n$ that satisfies
$(1-{1 \over n}) f(x_n) = x_n$. Since $B$ is compact, $x_n$ has an accumulation point $x^*$ and continuity of $f$ gives $f(x^*) = x^*$.